# Leakcanary unresolved icons

Tags: android, build.gradle, leakcanary

I am trying to build my custom buildType which looks like this:

```
    beta {
        versionNameSuffix "-beta"
        debuggable true
    }
```

On the debug builds everything works well, but as soon I try to build the release or beta build, this error emerges:

```
Error:(209, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/leak_canary_icon').
Error:(210, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/leak_canary_display_activity_label').
Error:(212, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/leak_canary_LeakCanary.Base').
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I see that the merged manifest contains this entry:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/leak_canary_icon"
        android:label="@string/leak_canary_display_activity_label"
        android:taskAffinity="com.squareup.leakcanary"
        android:theme="@style/leak_canary_LeakCanary.Base" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What did I do wrong? I've read the FAQ section and properly included betaCompile entry to my gradle file, so now it look as follows:

```
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
betaCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
```

I tried to clean/rebuild the project but the error is still present. Moreover, if I remove leakcanary code from the app and the dependencies from the gradle file, I am still getting this error, which is very strange since the leakcanary should not be present in the project at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this issue by creating custom icons (res/drawable/leak_canary_icon.png), custom string (leak_canary_display_activity_label) and custom theme that is just child of my default apptheme. The code for string and theme is here:

in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="leak_canary_LeakCanary.Base" parent="AppTheme"></style>
```

in res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="leak_canary_display_activity_label">Leaks view</string>
```

This allowed me to build the app, but I am not sure if it solves the issue completely.

Comment: hey @Malba, I am not 100% sure but I don't think so.